# How do I make the wheelchart figure text not mess-up the figure

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am very much new to using LaTeX. I am preparing my resume and went through this figure which shows my skills in the form of a wheel chart. It is not neat, the text keeps overlaying the figure and the figure is not centered properly and I don't want the text to over flow to right side section of the page as well. Please help me with this?

.tex:

```
\profilesection{Hard Skills}
    \wheelchart{3.7em}{2em}{%
        20/3em/yellow!75/\mbox{Object Oriented Programming},
        30/4em/Opal!40/C\#,
        30/3em/blue!75/.NET Core,
        30/3em/orange!75/\mbox{Software Engineering}
    }
```

.cls:

```
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[4][-90]{%
\def\outerradius{#2}%
\def\innerradius{#3}%
% Calculate total
\pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}%
\foreach\value/\colour/\name in {#4} {%
    \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}%
    \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

    % Rotate so we start from the top
    \begin{scope}[rotate=#1, on background layer]
    % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the
    % wheel
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
    \foreach \value/\width/\colour/\name in {#4} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

        % Calculate the percent value
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
        % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

        % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
        \pgfmathparse{
            (-\midangle>180?"west":"east")
        } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{
            (-\midangle>180?"flush left":"flush right")
        } \edef\textalign{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle<180)}

        % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so
        % we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
        \filldraw[draw=white,fill=\colour]
            (-\cumnum:\outerradius)
            arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius)
            -- (-\newcumnum:\innerradius)
            arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius)
            -- cycle;

        % Draw the data labels
        \draw [*-,thin,wheelchartlabelcolor] node [append after command={
            (\midangle:\midradius pt) --
            (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) --
            (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [
            xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=1ex,
            outer sep=0pt,
            text width=\width,
            anchor=\textanchor,
            align=\textalign,
            font=\small,
            text=wheeltextcolor
        ]{\name};
        % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
        \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
    }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}\par
```

}

Figure:

[image]